# Profile C++ calls from a C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, profiling

We are using a 3rd party software, which has massive native C++ core and quite a large C# with CLR part. 
They are not isolated in terms of I cannot simply run the native part without C#.

Now I've been profiling the C# part with dotTrace and realized that it does not really resolve calls to the unmanaged layer. It basically says that it consumed some time in native layer, which is opaque to me.

For native applications we are using Visual Studios build in profiler. The issue is, when I start the C# application, I am unable to bring the profiler into unmanaged mode to profile C++.

Is this technically possible? I am not asking for a specific tool (albeit nice to know) but rather want to know whether this is possible at all.

Is there a technical limitation, preventing the sampling of native calls, ignoring the managed part on top? Is there a specific requirement on the profiler, that must be able to profile both (although Visual Studio profiler can do both, just not at the same time)

The web has surprisingly little to say about such scenarios.

Comment: Do you use Performance Wizard in Visual Studio to profile your application? Can you please try CPU Usage Tool which does not have limitations in profiling mixed applications? You can find more information about CPU Usage Tool [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/29/profile-your-cpu-in-the-debugger-in-visual-studio-2015) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn971856.aspx).

Comment: @AndreyKriachko I only see [External Code] even if I enabled native code debugging in the application.

Comment: CPU Usage Tool gets the information from debugger whether code is external or not. And debugger should generally treat native code as a user one unless it is code from CLR, Windows, etc (see [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/06/26/just-my-code-for-c-in-vs-2013/) for more details).

Comment: I can only recommend enable "Show External Code" option in CPU Tool to treat all code as a user one. See [this picture](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/library/dn971856.05c43286-c820-468f-b0f3-af410f2d0d02(v=vs.140).jpeg).

Comment: @AndreyKriachko this indeed helped me a lot! Thank you. I did not even think about that External Code points to non "Just My Code" code and was thinking that it pointed to external code for the type of profiling. I see much information now but there are still some "Function Names" which are only named `user32.dll` or `ntoskrnl.exe` without the respective function which was called in there.

Comment: If you see module name as function name this means that symbols were not resolved for this module. I'd say it is expected for system modules like user32.dll or ntoskrnl.exe because typically you do not have PDBs for them. Do you have PDBs for that native C++ core? If not then CPU Usage tool will be able to resolve symbols and call tree will not show valid function names.

Comment: * then CPU Usage tool will NOT be able to resolve symbols